# how to remove an item from a std::list

Tags: c++, list

My code:

```
using namespace std;

class A{public: 
  int a; 
  A(int itemA) {a=itemA;}
};
class B:A{public:
  int b; 
  B(int itemA, int itemB) {a=itemA; b=itemB;}
};

class C{
  list<A> a;
  list<B> b;
  void transferAB(const A& pA, int itemb){
    a.remove(pA);
    b.push_back(B(pA.a, itemb));
  }
```

How do I make this thing work?

Answer (score 2):

`list` doesn't know how to compare your objects. You need to specify an equality operator (`operator==`) for your classes.

You can avoid this by store **pointers** to your objects, and the `list` will compare pointers when you call `remove`. Since pointers are simply numbers, there is no problem with comparison.

Comment: use a shared_ptr<> or unique_ptr<> wrapper instead of raw pointers, the OP will be much happier with them, and they still provide comparison operators.

Comment: @gbjbaanb - You know I rarely find myself using those. I think it's a combination of being used to handling my own memory as my #1 priority, and a case of slow adoption of better ways of coding :)

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the semantics will be quite different. Using pointers, equality identifies if two objects are the same one, not whether they have the same value.

Answer (score 1):

```
a.remove(pA);
```

You need overload `operator ==` for `A` as Aesthete suggest, or use `remove_if`, thats receive predicate and pass predicate to it. http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/remove_if/